# Google sheets API - Cannot append data in ProtectedRange column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I created a new sheet using API

```
fetch(
        `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${docId}/values/${sheetName}?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`,
        {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ values: tableInfo }),
        }
      )
```

After creating the google I set the first column (A) as protected and hidden, I used the batchUpdate API to do that using the code below

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formatDetails),
  };
  try {
    const formatApi = await fetch(
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}:batchUpdate`,
      options
    );
    const formatRes = await formatApi.json();
    return formatRes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Format Column Error: ", error);
  }

const formatDetails = {
requests: [
{
    updateDimensionProperties: {
      properties: {
        hiddenByUser: true,
      },
      fields: "hiddenByUser",
      range: {
        sheetId: tabId,
        dimension: "COLUMNS",
        startIndex: 0,
        endIndex: 1,
      },
    },
  }
},
{
    addProtectedRange: {
      protectedRange: {
        protectedRangeId: tabId,
        range: {
          sheetId: tabId,
          startRowIndex: 0,
          startColumnIndex: 0,
          endColumnIndex: 1,
        },
        description: "Protected! Cannot edit",
        warningOnly: true,
        requestingUserCanEdit: true,
      },
    },
  }
}
]
```

Now I use sheets API append a row in the sheet like below:

```
var result = await fetch(
    `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}/values/${sheetName}:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ values: data }),
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Update Sheet Error: ", error);
    })
```

When I append the row, the protected cell is not getting appended with the value.

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
Data A1 | Data B1 | Data C1 --> Data already in the sheet
Data A2 | Data B2 | Data C2 --> Data already in the sheet
         Data A3 | Data B3 | Data C3 --> New data
```

After appending the sheet looks like above.
Please help me how to fix this.
Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation from your question. I have 3 questions. 1. Who is the owner of the Spreadsheet? 2. About `I used the batchUpdate API to set this like below`, who is running this script? 3. About `Now I use sheets API append values to append a row in the sheet like below:`, who is running this script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the response. My answers: 1. Owner of the spreadsheet is same as the editor, 2. Google account owner runs the script, 3. the owner runs the script from the browser. Hope I am clear enough!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, the owner of Spreadsheet runs all scripts. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that when you put the values to the protected cells, the values can be put. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a detailed flow for correctly replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike When I put values to the protected cell (column A) it cannot be put. I have edited my question to give more details. hope its helpful

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply and updated question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: With this modification, can I append multiple rows?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your new question of `With this modification, can I append multiple rows?`, I think that it's yes. In that case, please use a 2-dimensional array including multiple rows to `data`. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize. By the way, can I ask you about whether your initial question was resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw your showing script, I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to "Method: spreadsheets.values.append". In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
var result = await fetch(
    `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}/values/${sheetName}:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ values: data }),
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Update Sheet Error: ", error);
    })
```

#### To:

```js
const token = "###"; // Please set your value.
const spreadSheetId = "###"; // Please set your value.
const sheetName = "###"; // Please set your value.
const data = [[###]]; // Please set your value.

const res = await fetch(
  `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}/values/${sheetName}`,
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  }
)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Update Sheet Error: ", error);
  });

const range = `'${sheetName}'!A${res.values.length + 1}`;
var result = await fetch(
  encodeURI(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}/values/${range}?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`),
  {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ values: data }),
  }
)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Update Sheet Error: ", error);
  })
```

- In this modification, first, in order to retrieve the last row number, the values are retrieved. After the row number is retrieved, the values of `data` are put into the cells using "Method: spreadsheets.values.update". By this, the values are put from column "A".

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: one question why do we have to encodeURI(url) in this case?

Comment: @Safi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `one question why do we have to encodeURI(url) in this case?`, I used it just in case. I think that if no error occurs in your actual situation even when `encodeURI` is not used, you are not required to use it.